# How to get outer object in elasticsearch from highlightfield

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some documents like this:

```
{
"content": "DocumentFile",
"title": "no title",
"post_id": "18",
"url": "http://localhost/wp/?p=18",
"attachments": [{
    "content": "Hi this is extrach data of file",
    "hash": "UPR9BC57IW3PUNTQ3LP79Q6UN0V3ZR7AAFJNUFGH",
    "name": "file."
}],
"isDeleted": "false",
"__creationdDate": "1456758952671"}
```

and I initialize elastic Search mapping so:

```
{
"post": {
    "properties": {
        "content": {
            "type": "string",
        },
        "title": {
            "type": "string",
        },
        "url": {
            "type": "string",
        },
        "post_id": {
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
                "raw": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        },
        "attachments": {
            "type": "nested",
            "include_in_parent": true,
            "properties": {
                "hash": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "vira_analyzer"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "vira_analyzer"
                },
                "content": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "vira_analyzer"
                }
            }
        },
        "_uid": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "vira_analyzer"
        }
    }
}}
```

and I add title,content,attachments.name , attachments.content to highlightfields

I search data in this document
it is in attachments.content and elasticsearch find it
now i want to get hash code of this attachment, what should i do ?
is there any option that elastic search give me the block of the attachment that have search query in name or content ??
by this:

> Text[] highlightFragments = hitHighLights.get(field).getFragments();

elastic search me just the content field of that attachment. I want all of that block, some thing like this:

```
{
    "content": "Hi this is extrach data of file",
    "hash": "UPR9BC57IW3PUNTQ3LP79Q6UN0V3ZR7AAFJNUFGH",
    "name": "file."
}
```

(a way is to get source of that document and search in it but it is not good because the speed decrease a lot.)

Comment: could you give an example of query you are currently using and the expected result and actual result